# How can I get GWT RequestFactory to with in a Gadget?

Tags: gwt-rpc, requestfactory

How can I get GWT RequestFactory to with in a Gadget?

Getting GWT-RPC to work with Gadgets is explained [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/GadgetsFAQ#How_can_I_get_GWT_RPC_to_work_in_a_Gadget?).

I'm looking for a analogous solution for **RequestFactory**.

I tried using the GadgetsRequestBuilder, so far I've managed to get the request to the server using:

```
requestFactory.initialize(eventBus, new DefaultRequestTransport() {

        @Override
        protected RequestBuilder createRequestBuilder() {
            return new GadgetsRequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST,
                    getRequestUrl());
        }

        @Override
        public String getRequestUrl() {
            return "http://....com/gadgetRequest";
        }

    });
```

But I end up with the following error:

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:694)
    at com.google.gwt.autobean.server.impl.JsonSplittable.create(JsonSplittable.java:35)
    at com.google.gwt.autobean.shared.impl.StringQuoter.split(StringQuoter.java:35)
    at com.google.gwt.autobean.shared.AutoBeanCodex.decode(AutoBeanCodex.java:520)
    at com.google.gwt.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:121)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach for sending a RequestFactory payload should be the same as RPC. You can see the payload that's being received by the server by running it with the JVM flag `-Dgwt.rpc.dumpPayload=true`.  My guess here is that the server is receiving a request with a zero-length payload.  What happens if you set up a simple test involving a  `GadgetsRequestBuilder` sending a `POST` request to your server?  Do you still get the same zero-length payload behavior?